# python object in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to save the object `candle` in the dictionary `candlebuffer`, however it gives me the error below. I am struggling; what is incorrect with my syntax?

```
    class Observer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listeners = []

    def attach(self, listener):
        if not listener in self.listeners:
            self.listeners.append(listener)

    def notify(self, event):
        for listener in self.listeners:
            listener.update(event)


class CandleGenerator(Observer):
    def __init__(self,freq):
        Observer.__init__(self)
        self.freq = freq
        self.candle = Candle()

    def update(self,tick):
        self.candle.addTick(tick,self.freq) 
        if keyfunc(self.candle.timestamp,self.freq) != self.candle.ref_timestamp:
            self.notify(self.candle)
            self.candle = Candle()

class CandlePrinter:
    def update(self, candle):
        print "Bougie>>>>>> freq: %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s " % (candle.freq,candle.last_price,candle.volume, candle.timestamp, candle.ref_timestamp, candle.open_price,candle.high_price,candle.low_price, candle.last_price)

class CandleBuffer:
    def __init__(self,candle):
        self.candlebuffer={0: candle}
    def update(self,candle):
        self.candlebuffer[candle.timestamp]= candle
        print self.candlebuffer


print('begin')

tickGenerator = TickGenerator()
candleGenerator1 = CandleGenerator(1)

candlePrinter = CandlePrinter()      
candleBuffer = CandleBuffer(5)    

tickGenerator.attach(candleGenerator1)
candleGenerator1.attach(candlePrinter)
candleGenerator1.attach(candleBuffer)

tickGenerator.generate()
```

It gives the following output:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: You are not showing us the code that actually causes the error. The stack trace tells you the exact line that it occurs. Please give the *whole* stack trace, not just the error message, and include the actual line with the error.

Comment: If that is 2.x then your class should inherit from `object` to support the "new" style classes. Could you show more code? i.e. the code using that class.

Comment: the error comes from this execution line indeed : candleBuffer = CandleBuffer()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have confirmed what I was suspecting, you have to pass another argument to the constructor, and use a dictionary instead of a set:

```
class CandleBuffer():
    def __init__(self,candle):
        self.candlebuffer={0 : candle}
    def update(self,candle):
        self.candlebuffer[candle.timestamp]= candle

# ...
candleBuffer = CandleBuffer(a_candle)
candleBuffer.update(another_candle)
```

Comment: it works indeed when i corrected the problem with the ":" raised and also i pass an argument "5" to the constructor, however i dont get it, where is it used? I know it is not straightforward for you to explain this...

Comment: also i added some more codes above, CandlePrinter and CandleBuffer looks similar to me, why the buffer would need an argument to be passed?

Comment: @matel Because you indicate it in the signature of the constructor: `self` is referred to the instance, and `candle` is another mandatory argument. As @xr09 points out, you can set a default value with `def __init__(self, candle=None):`.

Comment: thanks that is where it gets a bit complicated for me, i am new and dont have all the basis required yet

Answer (score 1):

This isn't what cause your error but you need to use : to create a dictionary.

```
self.candlebuffer = { 0 : candle }
```

It's on the format key : value.

I guessing that you're creating a CandleBuffer without giving an argument somewhere else in your code.